# How can I implement previous/next buttons in an image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image-gallery

I have a GridView populate from a database. When i click an image in the GridView, it opens in a new image called `imgFull`. This image may explain more:

[image: this is my image]

I want to put next and previous button to get in my div the next image from database.
I want to develop it in jQuery or JavaScript. This is a sample of my code:

```
<div>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
  Font-Names="Arial">
 <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="Image Name" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview Image">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "images/"     +Eval("FilePath")  %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" Style="cursor: pointer" OnClientClick = "return LoadDiv(this.src);"/>

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
    </div>

  <div id="divBackground" class="modal">

 </div>
 <div id="divImage" class = "info"> 
           <input id="btnNext" type="button" value="next" />
                <input id="Button1" type="button" value="left" />
           <input id="Button2" type="button" value="right" />
            <img id="imgLoader" alt=""
             src="~/images/loader.gif" />

          <img id="imgFull" runat="server" alt="" src=""  style="height: 500px;width: 590px"/>

 <input id="btnClose" type="button" value="close" onclick="HideDiv()"/>
 </div>
```

Would someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

your previous/next buttons will need click event handlers:

```
$('#yourNextButtonId').bind('click', function(){
    sendAjaxRequestFunction();
}
```

make an ajax call to a server-side script (such as php), which will return the path of the image you want to display.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./scripts/chatLogout.php",
    type: "post",
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        $('#yourImageId').attr('src', response);    
    }   
});
```

this is just one solution.

depending on the size of your gallery, you can also load all your images upfront, and use jquery/javascript to toggle the visibility of the appropriate image.

Comment: no i want to load just the shown page of gridview i think it can be in jquery or javascript just